# How can I avoid the transformation into an atomic vector in a matrix (r programming)

Tags: r, matrix, data-wrangling

I am desperately trying to find a solution to my problem. I am trying to build a graph with only a certain level of correlation. As I don't know how to filter with ggraph, I thought of replacing the values of my matrix by 0. Here is the way I proceed:

```
matrix[matrix== 1] <- 0.00 #replace 1 by 0
matrix[matrix<= 0.27] <- 0.00 #replace all value under 0.27 by zero
```

But the problem is that this converts my vectors into atomic vectors which interferes with the construction of the graph.
I have created a code that reproduces the problem :

```
M1 <- as_tibble(replicate(21,sample(1:3,100,rep=TRUE))) 
M2 <- as.matrix(round(cor(M1[,],method ="kendall"),2))
M2[,2] <- 0.09
M2[M2 == 1] <- 0.00
M2[M2 <= 0.10] <- 0
```

Comment: M2 is still a matrix after all those operations. Did you not want that?

Comment: After running your code, I get `class(M2)`, `[1] "matrix" "array"`, and `dim(M2)`, 
`[1] 21 21`

Comment: I want a matrix but the dimension 2 turns into an atomic vector, while I would like it to remain "normal". Am I precise enough or do I have to add some elements? In fact, it's for the further operations that I don't want any atomic vector because it's a problem.

Comment: A matrix is an atomic vector that is wrapped to x rows by y columns. What further processing is causing a problem? You can always convert it to a tibble with `as_tibble` or a data frame with `as.data.frame`.

Comment: My problem comes when I launch my code for the graph: 
ggraph(gr4ph, layout = "lgl") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(), angle_calc = 'along',label_dodge = unit(2.5, 'mm')) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size=4,color= name)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name,size=4), repel = TRUE)
Not knowing how to filter with ggraph I thought that a way to get around the problem would be to filter the correlation matrix myself before passing it into ggraph. The problem is that it makes isolated points appear that I can't remove.